# CSS is not applying completely to HTML file

Tags: html, css, sass

Still very new to CSS, I have a CSS that's meant to make images animate up after every few seconds. I tested the CSS with an HTML code and it worked fine. But when the same CSS was imported into a different project, it looked broken; images are not animating completely (see image)

[image: the image only animates halfway up]

Here is the css code:

```css
.ad-container {
  @include screen-calc(width, 521px);
  @include screen-calc(height, 71.5px);
  @include screen-calc(left, 1399px);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(186, 186, 187, 1);
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: var(--ad-visibility);
}

.ad-image {
  @include screen-calc(max-height, 72px);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.animation-slide-ad-down {
  --ad-animation-duration: 10s;
   :first-child:nth-last-child(2) {
    animation: ad-animation-two calc(var(--ad-animation-duration) * 2) both infinite;
  }
   :first-child:nth-last-child(3) {
    animation: ad-animation-three calc(var(--ad-animation-duration) * 3) both infinite;
  }
   :first-child:nth-last-child(4) {
    animation: ad-animation-four calc(var(--ad-animation-duration) * 4) both infinite;
  }
   :first-child:nth-last-child(5) {
    animation: ad-animation-five calc(var(--ad-animation-duration) * 5) both infinite;
  }
   :first-child:nth-last-child(6) {
    animation: ad-animation-six calc(var(--ad-animation-duration) * 6) both infinite;
  }
  @keyframes ad-animation-two {
    0% {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    49% {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    50% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -1);
    }
    99% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -1);
    }
    100% {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
  }
  @keyframes ad-animation-three {
    0% {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    32% {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    33% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -1);
    }
    65% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -1);
    }
    66% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -2);
    }
    99% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -2);
    }
    100% {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
  }
  @keyframes ad-animation-four {
    0% {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    24% {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    25% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -1);
    }
    49% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -1);
    }
    50% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -2);
    }
    74% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -2);
    }
    75% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -3);
    }
    99% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -3);
    }
    100% {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
  }
  @keyframes ad-animation-five {
    0% {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    19% {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    20% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -1);
    }
    39% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -1);
    }
    40% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -2);
    }
    59% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -2);
    }
    60% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -3);
    }
    79% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -3);
    }
    80% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -4);
    }
    99% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -4);
    }
    100% {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
  }
  @keyframes ad-animation-six {
    0% {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    15.67% {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    16.67% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -1);
    }
    32.34% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -1);
    }
    33.34% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -2);
    }
    49% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -2);
    }
    50% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -3);
    }
    65.67% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -3);
    }
    66.67% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -4);
    }
    82.34% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -4);
    }
    83.34% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -5);
    }
    99% {
      margin-top: calc(6.66666vh * -5);
    }
    100% {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

And the html looks like this:

```html
{{var "ticker-animate-scroll-class" (concat "fx-animate-scroll-x-" properties.scrollSpeed)}}

<div class="ticker universal">
    <div class="logo-bug">
        <img src="{{properties.logo}}" class="flo-bug">
    </div>
    
    <div class="ticker-message">
        <div class="message">
            <div class="message-text animate-scroll animate-scroll__{{properties.scrollSpeed}}">
                <span class="component">{{ properties.message }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="message-gradient-right"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="ad-container animation-slide-ad-down">
        <img src="{{properties.ad1}}" class="ad-image component" />
        <img src="{{properties.ad2}}" class="ad-image component" />
        <img src="{{properties.ad3}}" class="ad-image component" />
        <img src="{{properties.ad4}}" class="ad-image component" />
        <img src="{{properties.ad5}}" class="ad-image component" />
        <img src="{{properties.ad6}}" class="ad-image component" />
    </div>
</div>
```

When I check the browser console, there are a few striked out css codes (see image)

[image: striked out css properties]

Please how do I fix this issue?

Comment: If some of the CSS properties are getting strikes out then it may be that some other CSS is cutting over the CSS on the page in question. Either try to find which CSS is cutting out the other CSS or else use the !important attribute beside the CSS declarations which are getting striked out. This will force the browser to follow the specific CSS instruction with that attribute.

Comment: It is almost never a good idea to use `!important` to solve problems like this, other than to simply test and see what is getting overwritten. It totally ignores the inherent specificity rules in CSS and goes straight to the brute force solution. This results in sloppy code that is constantly needing more `!important`s and is a giant maintenance headache. Use of `!important` should be as minimal as possible. Use it only as a last resort, for testing, or very specific use case like certain helper/utility classes. See here: https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: Could you provide a working example that can demonstrate your issue? For example, a codesanbox or codepan. And without a working example, I can only guess that you try to make this line `overflow: hidden;` to `overflow: visible` and see if the problem persists or not